# How to reset back to running 'python' in terminal to Python2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, terminal

I used to have python3.6, but recently I changed to python3.10. I switched to setting in terminal 'python2' to python2.7 and 'python3' to python3.10, but now I get this issue when I run 'python' in terminal:

```
dyld[1193]: dyld cache '/System/Library/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h' not loaded: syscall to map cache into shared region failed
dyld[1193]: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file)
Abort trap: 6
```

I think it is still trying to point towards python3.6 and I forgot how to change it. How do I switch 'python' in terminal back to running its default (python2.7)?

Comment: Please add information such as your OS and terminal details. Also check if you have **Python 3.6** uninstalled

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.